# SQLiteConnection.Open fails without exception on deployment

Tags: c#, sqlite

Quite a while ago, I created a C# WPF application with a SQLite Database. It works fine, however I lost the code and am now trying to recreate it. (I'm adding this, because I did have it working at one point, including deployement on mine and a different computer. I just can't get it to work correctly now.)

Here is my issue: Starting the program from Visual Studio (2015, in this case), everything works just fine, both in Debug and in Release.

I created an installation using the Visual Studio Installation thingy and installed the program on my development machine. When I try to run the program, it exits without error message or exception. After putting in a number of logging statements, I found that it always fails here:

```
this.str_db_path = "DataSource=C:\\ProgramData\\GSS\\Buchhaltung.db;Version=3;";
this.db_connection = new SQLiteConnection(this.str_db_path);

try
{
     gLogger.Logger.AddToLog("Test opening.");
     this.db_connection.Open();  // fails here
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     gLogger.Logger.AddToLog("Open failed.");
     gLogger.Logger.AddToLog(String.Format("Exception: {0}", ex.Message));
}

gLogger.Logger.AddToLog("Test worked. Closing now.");
this.db_connection.Close();
```

The file exists and I do have access to it.

I have tried putting the file in different places. I also tried different versions of the string for the db path (w/o Version=3, w/o semicolon the the end, w/o 3).

If the file is not in the specified place or the string for the path is not correct, I do get an exception. However, if the file is there and the path is written correctly, db_connection.Open() always fails without an exception being thrown.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked at any database logs or in the Windows Event Viewer?

Comment: what exception are you logging in the try catch block?

Comment: There is nothing in this code that shows (or even tests) if the connection is open or not.

Comment: Also, there's nothing here to explain how your application exits because the database connection failed to open.

Comment: use sysinternals procmon - it will show you all the file operations that your app does

Comment: @Chris: I didn't know about the Windows Event Viewer. Thank you for that advice! Using that, I was finally able to see the exception thrown. Turns out, the setup project kept copying the wrong SQLite.Interop.dll. Fixed that and now it works. Though I still have no idea, why that particular exception never got shown in my log file.